# Getting the values from a column based on a string from another column and returning a unique list from result

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table that has two columns that I'm interested in. What I want to do is lookup a string in the the first column but save the strings from the second column in a range. Also I would like the values to be unique.

I was thinking of looping through the entire first column, but given that I have in excess of 20000 rows I was wondering if there are better methods that will automatically find the values and save them as a range.

Here's and example of how my table looks:

[image]

So what I want is save as a range all the strings in column D when column A has value AAA, for example. I know that I can do this easily with advanced filter but I want to do it in VBA.

Thanks

Comment: Hate to be the one to point this out to you, but saying "I want to do it in VBA" without providing anything written in VBA is a bit of a tough request to make. SO doesn't work this way. Write the code, then ask for help. Still, since this issue is so simple it's been done to death already, see my answer below. How to return a unique list and how to transfer it to another range is entirely up to you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
Sub FilterRange(WS As Worksheet, FieldIndex As Long, CriteriaStr As String)
    WS.AutoFilterMode = False
    Set Rng = WS.UsedRange
    Rng.AutoFilter FieldIndex, CriteriaStr, Operator:=xlFilterValues, VisibleDropDown:=False
End Sub
```

Call it like this:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim WS As Worksheet: Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3") 'Modify as necessary.
    Dim ColOfCondition As Long
    ColOfCondition = Application.Match("HeaderA", WS.Rows(1), 0)
    FilterRange WS, ColOfCondition, "AAA"

End Sub
```

Gives a result like this:

[image]

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the code. It seems to work but the problem is I want the range variable to have only values from one column not all the other columns.